# New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile - Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Tags: yaml, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-image-builder

i am trying to create a new AzRoleDefinition within an Azure pipeline with the YAML but i receive an error

below my yaml for the pipeline:

```
name: 'Powershell'
trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
  - job: my_job
    timeoutInMinutes: 120
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 3
    pool: 'Azure Pipelines'
    steps:

    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: 'test'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'azureinfo'
        azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/powershell'
        Inline: |
     

          $myRoleImageCreationPath = ".\myRoleImageCreation.json"
          $subscriptionID = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id
          $imageResourceGroup = 'RG-WE-AVD-ACG'
          $imageRoleDefName="Custom Role AIB Pipe"

          $Content = Get-Content -Path $myRoleImageCreationPath -Raw
          $Content = $Content -replace '<subscriptionID>', $subscriptionID
          $Content = $Content -replace '<rgName>', $imageResourceGroup
          $Content = $Content -replace 'Azure Image Builder Service Image Creation Role', $imageRoleDefName
          $Content | Out-File -FilePath $myRoleImageCreationPath -Force
        
          New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile $myRoleImageCreationPath
```

error log

```
2023-04-02T18:45:01.9886433Z ##[section]Starting: test
2023-04-02T18:45:01.9891615Z ==============================================================================
2023-04-02T18:45:01.9891784Z Task         : Azure PowerShell
2023-04-02T18:45:01.9891873Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
2023-04-02T18:45:01.9891977Z Version      : 5.218.0
2023-04-02T18:45:01.9892040Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-04-02T18:45:01.9892134Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurepowershelltroubleshooting
2023-04-02T18:45:01.9892229Z ==============================================================================
2023-04-02T18:45:02.3947087Z Generating script.
2023-04-02T18:45:02.3979550Z [command]/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/20a4d47f-6ea6-4006-ad79-4134328fd8dd.ps1'
2023-04-02T18:45:02.4042584Z Saved!
2023-04-02T18:45:03.9853492Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name /usr/share/az_9.3.0/Az.Accounts/2.12.1/Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
2023-04-02T18:45:04.6779259Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2023-04-02T18:45:04.8075005Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2023-04-02T18:45:05.1564251Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant 55a3fdf6-67a6-48d5-b825-1eaabecb27be -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
2023-04-02T18:45:05.9367076Z ##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 6810f60a-9fbe-413a-bd28-e7e813507521 -TenantId 55a3fdf6-67a6-48d5-b825-1eaabecb27be
2023-04-02T18:45:09.0193054Z [31;1mNew-AzRoleDefinition: [0m/home/vsts/work/_temp/20a4d47f-6ea6-4006-ad79-4134328fd8dd.ps1:15
2023-04-02T18:45:09.0193738Z [36;1mLine |
2023-04-02T18:45:09.0194624Z [36;1m  15 | [0m [36;1mNew-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile $myRoleImageCreationPath[0m
2023-04-02T18:45:09.0195037Z [36;1m     | [31;1m ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-04-02T18:45:09.0195344Z [31;1m[36;1m     | [31;1mOperation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
2023-04-02T18:45:09.0195628Z [0m
2023-04-02T18:45:09.1158937Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2023-04-02T18:45:09.1187370Z ##[section]Finishing: test
```

could maybe someone help any explain what the problem could be?

Thanks

create a new AzRoleDefinition within an Azure pipeline with the YAML

Answer (score 1):

> ***I ran Azure DevOps pipeline to create New-AzRoleDefinition by running this command from this MS Document link -
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroledefinition?view=azps-9.6.0
> in my yaml task and received the same error code, Refer below:-***

[image]

**Error:-**

```
New-AzRoleDefinition: /home/vsts/work/_temp/xxxx-b6a3-4a8c-812e-dcf6278efc3b.ps1:16
16 | New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile $myRoleImageCreationPath
 | Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

***This error occurs when your service connection selected at azureSubscription  while running python does not have Owner or User Access Administrator role assigned at subscription level to create Role definitions in Azure:-***

***When I used the Service connection with Owner role assigned to it, The Pipeline worked and the New Role definition code ran successfully***, Refer below:-

**My YAML Pipeline script:-**

```yaml
name: 'Powershell'

trigger: none

pr: none

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

jobs:

- job: my_job

timeoutInMinutes: 120

cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 3

pool: 'Azure Pipelines'

steps:

  

- task: AzurePowerShell@5

displayName: 'test'

inputs:

azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'

ScriptType: 'InlineScript'

Inline: |

$myRoleImageCreationPath = ".\myroles.json"

$subscriptionID = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id

$imageResourceGroup = 'siliconpurview'

$imageRoleDefName="Custom Role AIB Pipe"

$Content = Get-Content -Path $myRoleImageCreationPath -Raw

$Content = $Content -replace '0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7', $subscriptionID

$Content = $Content -replace 'siliconpurview', $imageResourceGroup

$Content = $Content -replace 'Azure Image Builder Service Image Creation Role', $imageRoleDefName

$Content | Out-File -FilePath $myRoleImageCreationPath -Force

New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile $myRoleImageCreationPath

azurePowerShellVersion: 'latestVersion'

workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/powershell'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***The service principal used to create Service connection PowershellSid has Owner role assigned at the subscription level,*** Refer below:-

[image]